# Как создать WordPress модуль для контекта который повторяет шаблон верстки?

Tags: php, wordpress, cms

В модуле должно быть три текстовых поля и еще одно для картинки. Средствами модуля требуется создать несколько записи в базе данных (там будут храниться три эти поля и картинка). Модуль должен подключаться к странице и отображать на ней синтаксически одинаковые блоки с разной информацией. 
Дело в том что я раньше работал с Joomla и не знаю как устроен WordPress. Расскажите хотя бы в общих чертах как это сделать?

Comment: господи, джумловоды еще существуют?:) 
(ACF wordpress, wp-kama.ru, Polylang - multi-lang plugin, Contact Form 7) - все необходимые плагины + сразу же прочитай за темплейты, чтобы не плодить шаблоны и для мультиязычности удобно

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Расскажите хотя бы в общих чертах как это сделать?

[Произвольные поля](https://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8F) в админке и их вывод в нужном [шаблоне темы](https://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%98%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%85%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2).

Если что - для удобной работы с ПП есть масса разных плагинов.
Или [написать свой](https://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0) со всем необходимым функционалом

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста какой нибудь существующий

Comment: На выбор: https://wordpress.org/plugins/search.php?q=custom+fields (выбирать нужно новое и совместимое с используемой версией ВП). WCK, Type - достаточно мощные. Может что и попроще пойдёт.